# UIImagePickerController After taking 5 images sequentially Terminates Application 

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, uipickerviewcontroller

```
 //This method Launches the picker to take the picture from camera. 
-(IBAction)takeyouphoto:(id)sender
{
     if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            // Create image picker controller

            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

            // Set source to the camera
            imagePicker2.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            // Delegate is self
            imagePicker2.delegate = self;
            // Allow editing of image ?
            imagePicker2.allowsEditing= NO;

            // Show image picker
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker2 animated:YES];

        }
}
//This is ImagePicker Delegate method. 
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 @try {
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
        {
            UIImage *resultimage=nil;
            //I am using iOS5, so we can not use NSAutoreleasePool
             resultimage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;

            //This Launches the HUD (Activity Indicator) because ImagePicker ususally takes 5  
             //seconds to launch image.
            [self showHUD:resultimage];
         }
    }
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)showHUD:(UIImage *)resultimage
{
    [[Singleton sharedmysingleton] stoptimer];
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading Image";
    //HUD.detailsLabelText=@"Loading";
    //Below call on showWhileExecuting of the MBProgressHuD class has its own NSAutoreleasePool
    //Defined in MGProgressHUD class. it also runs the method showimageincell; in separate 
    //thread.

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(showimagesincell:) onTarget:self withObject:resultimage animated:YES];

}
-(void)showimagesincell:(UIImage *)image
{

    appDelegate.tabbarcontroller.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    NSError *error;

     UIImage *resultImage=[self scale:image toSize:image.size];

    //UIImage *resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRefCrop scale:1.0 orientation:resultimage.imageOrientation];

    //resultimage.imageOrientation
    NSData *imagedata=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resultImage, 0.7);//(resultImage);



    UIImage *smallimage=[self scale:image toSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    NSData *smallimagedata=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallimage, 0.7);

    /* NSString *imagetypeid=[Fetchsavefromcoredata getImagenameandImageidfromdatabase:@"Mobile_ImageType" attributename:@"imageType" predicate:imagetypetxtfield.text];

     //write image to document directory
     NSString *localImagedir=[photodirpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:selectedvinnumber];
     NSString *datetime=[Singleton imagedateandtime];
     NSString *imagename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png",imagetypeid,datetime];
     NSString *localImagePath=[localImagedir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
     [imagedata writeToFile:localImagePath atomically:YES];*/

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updatetableview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)updatetableview
{
    [[Singleton sharedmysingleton] starttimer];
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}


-(UIImage *)scale:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}


//Above is all my code, I have tried to find it on diffrent forums but I have not fixed it yet.  
//Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Do you use ARC? Because I'm relatively sure you have a memory issue.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Are you use the picker delegate is not getting set to nil? can you post what error messages you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC. There is no error shown on debugger in console. It just terminates the app and sometimes its white screen.

Comment: running it with nszombies enabled?

Comment: No I haven't tried nszombies, I have used it earlier while writing non-arc code.

Comment: , since I am not getting any EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which can be a case for using NSZombies.

Comment: its still very less info out there for anyone to figure out whats going wrong. If you can at least tell where its crashing (based on break points), it'd be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white screen issue is fixed by  keeping the image returned by the UIIMagePickerController delegate method into an @autoreleasepool (for iOS5). It solved the problem, we can not use NSAutoreleasePool in ARC code.

Here the line of code in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: delegate method

```
UIImage *resultimage=nil;
@autoreleasepool
{
          //I am using iOS5, so we can not use NSAutoreleasePool
         resultimage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;

}
```

Below the  UIImagePickerController delegate method   after implementing @autoreleasepool

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 @try {
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
        {
            UIImage *resultimage=nil;
            @autoreleasepool
           {
              //I am using iOS5, so we can not use NSAutoreleasePool
              resultimage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] ;
           }

            //This Launches the HUD (Activity Indicator) because ImagePicker ususally takes 5  
             //seconds to launch image.
            [self showHUD:resultimage];
         }
    }
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```